# A catalog of online study groups

Tags: web-apps, search-engine

I need an online catalog of online study groups. A study group is a group of students studying a specific subject together. I need just a catalog, no forums. Forums may be external and maintained by group moderators. The only option I found is [OpenStudy](http://openstudy.com/). As described in [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/openstudy-collection-online-study-groups-subjects/), OpenStudy keeps discussions inside. Forums tied to online courses may count as study groups. They have disadvantages: their subjects are confined to that of the course; their content is not accessible to search engines; they are deleted after the course ends.

Comment: Now I am not sure that this catalog would be better then a plain web search service like Google. It is easy for group administrators to include the phrase "study group" or "learning community" into profiles of their groups.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you are looking for something like [**Moodle**](https://moodle.org/). It's an e-learning platform we use at our university. All students and teachers are registered by the management team and then assigned to their courses or "study groups" in your case. Inside these courses teachers provide details and materials for their courses and all assigned students can access the material.

Moodle is free and open source so you can try it without any costs if you own a server. If you do not own a server, there is also hosting available for Moodle.

*I'm not completely sure if the software matches your requirements but you may take a look at it. I can recommend it as it's working very well for us.*